# Instead of JMP ESP can we use it's opcodes?

Tags: buffer-overflow, assembly, debugging

In a buffer overflow exploit, when we use a JMP ESP instruction to jump to the ESP, instead of using the address of the JMP ESP, can't we use the opcodes of it?. I generated the opcodes of the JMP ESP instruction with mona in Immunity Debugger.

```
!mona assemble -s "JMP ESP"
```

Which was `\xff\xe4`

In my case, the offset where the program crashes is 204, and my payload looks like this.

```
payload_size = 4000

payload = b"".join([
    b"A"*204,
    p32(0x62501205),   # JMP ESP
    b'C' * (payload_size - offset - 4)
    ])
```

Here, instead of using the address where the JMP ESP instruction(0x62501205) is can't we use the instruction itself (`\xff\xe4`)? My final goal is to know if it is possible to use the opcodes of a function(JMP ESP in this case) instead of using the address of the function itself.

Comment: Did you understand why and how the exploit work with the address of the jump?

Comment: Yes, I think so. After the JMP ESP is executed, whatever we put at the ESP (C buffer) gets executed. So my question is can we use the opcodes of the JMP ESP instruction instead of the address of it?

Answer (score 1):

The address `0x62501205` override `EIP` that's why it works with the address of the instruction `JMP ESP`.

**Using the opcode**:

It will not work with the opcode `\xff\xe4` as only the two lowers bytes of `EIP` will be overwritten and the value of `EIP` will be: `0xXXXXffe4` (XXXX for the 2 High  unknown bytes).

If the address exist, the content (instruction) of this address will be executed else the program will crash.

**Using the address of `JMP ESP`**:

In this case `EIP` will be overwritten with the value of `ESP` (let's suppose that it contain the address of the buffer  `'C' * (payload_size - offset - 4)` ) which will lead to execute the instructions on the stack: `C` = `0x43` = `INC EBX`.

I think that debugging step by step both exploits, with the address of the jump and with the opcode, could help to better understand how it works.